# PHP and dynamic magic constants

Tags: php, constants

I am working on a class in which Im trying to pull back a way to set the `__FUNCTION__` magic constant in PHP dynamically.

**Code so far**

```
<?php

    class TestFunction {
        var $method = __FUNCTION__;

        public function __construct() {

        }

        public function testMethod() {
            return $this->method;
        }
    }
```

Its not working.. Im not sure if this is even possible... just trying to think outside the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__FUNCTION__` constant will only return the name of the currently executing function when you use it inside a function. `__METHOD__` will do the same for a method of a class but you have to use it inside your class method. In your example even if you replaced `__FUNCTION__` with `__METHOD__` it wouldn't work. If you're after the name of the class try `__CLASS__`